# CV with photo for postdoc application

Tags: cv, germany, europe, canada

I am preparing an updated CV for application for postdoc positions. Is it necessary to put a photo on a CV for postdoc positions?

Comment: Could you add a country tag? That depends a lot on your country, e.g. in the US you often don't have photos, while in some European countries it would be strange to not have one.

Comment: CANADA and also some European countries such as Germany.

Comment: I can't say about Canada. For Germany, I would put a photo as it is still rather common here, but I think considering the fact that you are (I guess?) not from Germany no one will discard your application just because the photo is missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CV formats vary widely between countries. In the US, Canada, the UK, Ireland, the Netherlands<sup>*</sup> and Sweden CVs **should not** include photos, as these could reveal personal information (on race, age, perhaps religion) that employers are not allowed to use under local laws ([source](https://us.experteer.com/magazine/should-you-put-a-photo-on-your-cv/)).

In many European countries, except those mentioned above, it used to be or still is **expected** to include a photo on your CV. However, in internationalized areas like academia, norms are converging toward the Anglo-American/Nordic model. German universities, for example, no longer expect photos on CVs, but it's not wrong to have them. I didn't put a photo on my application and got a postdoc in Austria.

I'm not sure about China and Japan.

<sub>*Another [source](https://www.sciencemag.org/careers/2005/02/dutch-first-impressions-cover-letters-and-cvs-netherlands) specifically on the Netherlands is less strict: Employers are reported as being indifferent, unless it's a high-ranking (e.g. international?) position, in which case including a photo is seen as "bad form".</sub>

Comment: Damn, I just applied to a job in the Netherlands with a photo on my CV; lucky me that the HR team is international and not familiar with Dutch standards I guess? :)

Comment: @DirkLiebhold Good luck! I guess they'll be familiar with Dutch standards, but they are certainly aware that they don't live on an island and that standards vary.

Comment: I think _must not_ should be _should not_: Inclusion doesn't violate local laws, discrimination (based upon inclusion) does. (Upvoted anyhow.)

Comment: @user2768 agreed.

Comment: Finland: Picture would be unusual. Denmark:  I've applied for a postdoc and an assistant professor position, and neither requested a picture. Norway: I applied to two postdocs and neither requested a picture. Based on this I would extrapolate that a picture is unusual in Nordic academic environments.

Comment: I can add the same for Sweden to @TommiBrander 's comment. No photo expected there.